# Why doesnot page get redirected?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have called a delete controller from ajax. Data is deleted and success function is executed but the page is not redirected to the new page mentioned in the controller.
Here is my ajax code:

```
                   function deletex(ids)
                 {
                   var x={id:ids};
                var a=confirm("are you sure to delete this data of id"+x["id"]);
                   if(a==true)
                     {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Delete",
            data: x,
            dataType:"HTML",
            success: function (data) {
                Set(data);
                alert("data is deleted");


            },
            error:
                function e()
                {
                    alert("error");
                }
        });
    } else 
        alert("You cancelled it");
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(long id)
    {
        country country = db.countries.Find(id);
        db.countries.Remove(country);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Create","countries");
    }
```

Comment: I think its not able to resolve the url, what console error you are getting??

Comment: There is no error in console just page does not get redirected to view mentioned in controller

Comment: Try setting window.location='@Url.Action("Create","countries")' in ajax success event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way for you to do it would have been, return a JSON object frm the delete controller which would indicate if delete was successfull or not and then from the ajax's success method, depending on the value of the returned JSON object, redirect to the action of your choice.

Comment: Thank you ,using Josn object to redirect object was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the script like bellow

```
<script>
    function deletex(ids) {
        var x = { id: ids };
        var a = confirm("are you sure to delete this data of id" + x["id"]);
        if (a == true) {
            alert(1);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Delete","CheckIn")',
                data: x,
                dataType: "Json" 
            });
        }
        else {
            alert("You cancelled it");
        }
    }

</script>
```

in thai I change dataType: "Html" To dataType: "Json"

And delete Ajax success and error function because it redirect to other page